# Need assistance with query logic

Tags: mysql, join, substring

I've become stuck with this problem and am not exactly sure how I should bring about my query.

I have two tables, one with **articles** and one with so called **ATC codes**.

An ATC code looks like this: `N02AA59`. This is a *full* code consisiting of 7 characters. Each character before the last one is a certain category. Thus `N02A` is also an ATC code.

Now my articles table contains far from all ATC codes.
What I want to achieve is a result set that is used in an autocomplete, in such a way, that all ATC codes substringed (char 1-6) should be part of a result set if - and only if - they lead up to an article with an ATC code that begins with those characters in my articles table.

For example, if I type in "N02A" in my autocomplete then the items that should be part of the result set are all ATC codes that start with "N02A", because we have an article that has the ATC code "N02AA59".

This is the basic query, but as you may guess, it only returns 7-char ATC codes, because no shorter ATC codes exist in my articles table:

```
SELECT _atc_codes.code, _atc_codes.name
FROM articles
JOIN _atc_codes
ON (_atc_codes.code LIKE 'N02A%' AND _atc_codes.id = articles.atc_code)
```

There's a twist to the whole query. The second column, the corresponding name field, must be that of the resulting ATC code. So if I search on "N02A", that doesn't mean that each item should have the name of the ATC code "N02A".

Comment: Have you tried something with `SUBSTR` function ? It could probably help you http://sql.sh/fonctions/substring

Comment: use a UNION of queries that return `SUBSTR`s of different lengths.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're after, but it's something about hierarchies isn't it? For instance, a search for N02AB (N02A) should throw up QN02AB53 (Fentanyl combos, right)

Comment: @Strawberry You're right about hierarchies, but N02AB should not match QN02AB53, the match is only on the right side (N02AB%).

Comment: OK, but (and watch as I step wildly outside anything I have even the faintest knowledge about) QN02AB53 (Fantanyl combos) IS a subcategory of N02AB (Phenylpiperidine derivatives)

Comment: @Strawberry The Q prefix denotes a veterinary product and are not of interest in my project. They're already filtered out from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem myself. This query gives me exactly the result set that I'm after:

```
SELECT `filtered`.code AS `value`, `filtered`.en AS `name`
FROM (SELECT _atc_codes.code, _atc_codes.en
      FROM _atc_codes
      WHERE _atc_codes.code LIKE 'N02A%') AS `filtered`
JOIN (SELECT _atc_codes.code
      FROM articles
      JOIN _atc_codes
      ON (_atc_codes.id = articles.atc_code)
      GROUP BY articles.atc_code) AS `articles`
WHERE articles.code LIKE CONCAT(`filtered`.code, '%')
GROUP BY `filtered`.code
```

The key is to compare two derived tables, and not JOIN two full tables.

Comment: Well done - although, in the absence of any aggregating functions, your use(s) of GROUP BY is inappropriate. Perhaps you're after the DISTINCT operator.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the reply. What in your opinion is the difference between `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`? Any performance gains in this particular case?

Comment: Yes, plus GROUP BY can (and will) lead to unpredictable results where multiple columns are selected (- so less of an issue in this instance)

Answer (score 0):

From the details in your question, I assuming you have two tables.
Table 1: **_atc_codes** with fields **code** and **name** (may be more).
Table 2: **articles** with field **atc_code** and other fields including **article** (which is not empty).
I did a test with this minimal information and your query works except for a small error.
In the query line `ON (_atc_codes.code LIKE 'N02A%' AND _atc_codes.id = articles.atc_code)` you are comparing **_atc_codes.id** to **articles.atc_code**
It should be **_atc_codes.code** and not **_atc_codes.id**
Please comment if there are additional details with respect to **_atc_codes.id** that was missing from the original post or if I am mistaken.